# Do we ever see Worf drink prune juice again?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

(Yesterday's Enterprise) The prune juice scene is such a classic TNG moment. It would seem that it would become a part of Worf forever, but I can't remember ever seeing him drink prune juice again. Did he?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Worf is seen drinking prune juice on five separate occasions in the official Trek Canon;  once on Star Trek : TNG and four times on Star Trek : DS9

He is initially introduced to the drink by Guinan in the TNG episode '**Yesterday's Enterprise**'.

He orders "*Chilled prune juice*" at Quark's bar and in the mess hall of the USS Defiant in the DS9 episodes '**The Way of the Warrior**' and '**The Quickening**" and an "*Extra large prune juice*" in the DS9 episodes '**To the Death**' and '**Let He Who Is Without Sin...**'

His love of prune juice is also mentioned by other characters in two episodes; TNG '**Family**' and DS9 '**Rules of Engagement**'

[image]

[Source](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prune_juice)

Comment: Nice! That makes me smile :)  Warrior's Drink!

Comment: @Jolenealaska - "Today is a good day to remain regular..."